# Nextjs tree shaking in api routes enabled? Unused code is affecting my bundle size

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using the NextJs api routes for uploading some documents into a postgress db.

However, I'm observing that **the build size is getting too big despite the fact that I'm not importing the code that is increasing the build size**.

This is the api/upload.ts file that imports the `langchainPrismaUpload` function from the utils/langchain.ts file:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { Form } from 'multiparty';

import { langchainPrismaUpload } from '@/utils/langchain';
import { getErrorMessage } from '@/utils/misc';
import { getExistingDocs } from '@/utils/drizzle';

// some type definitions here

export type UploadResponse = {
  fileExistsInDB: boolean;
  nameSpace: string;
};

export default async function handler(
  req: ApFDataRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse,
) {
  const form = new Form();
  const formData = await new Promise<FData>((resolve, reject) => {
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }

      const file = files.file[0];
      resolve({ file });
    });
  });

  const fileName = formData.file.originalFilename;

  try {
    const fileExistsInDB = await getExistingDocs(fileName);

    if (!fileExistsInDB) {
      try {
        // here's the only import from the utils/langchain.ts file
        await langchainPrismaUpload(formData.file.path, fileName);
      } catch (error) {
        const errMsg = getErrorMessage(error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: errMsg });
        return;
      }
    }

    const resData: UploadResponse = {
      fileExistsInDB: !!fileExistsInDB,
      nameSpace: fileName,
    };

    res.status(200).json(resData);
  } catch (error) {
    const errMsg = getErrorMessage(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: errMsg });
    return;
  }
}
```

and here's the function that I'm importing from the `utils/langchain.ts`. This file contains other functions that *are not being used nor imported* in the `api/upload.ts` file and even death code (yeah, shame on me) left there for reference:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf';

import { OpenAIEmbeddings } from 'langchain/embeddings/openai';
import { PDFLoader } from 'langchain/document_loaders/fs/pdf';
import { PineconeStore } from 'langchain/vectorstores/pinecone';
import { RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter } from 'langchain/text_splitter';
import { Document } from 'langchain/document';

export const langchainPrismaUpload = async (
  filePath: string,
  fileName: string,
) => {
  // use pdfjs to load pdf
  // https://js.langchain.com/docs/modules/indexes/document_loaders/examples/file_loaders/pdf
  const loader = new PDFLoader(filePath, {
    // pdfjs: () => import('pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.js'),
  });

  const pdf = await loader.load();

  // split into chunks
  const textSplitter = new RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter({
    chunkSize: 1000,
    chunkOverlap: 200,
  });

  // this outputs an array of Document objects
  const docs = await textSplitter.splitDocuments(pdf);

  await prisma.langChainDocs.create({
    data: {
      name: fileName,
      nameSpace: fileName,
      docs: {
        create: docs.map((doc) => ({
          name: fileName,
          metadata: JSON.stringify(doc.metadata),
          pageContent: doc.pageContent,
        })),
      },
    },
  });
};

// this is death code, I'm leaving it here in case I need to use it
// but it's not exported or used by any other function un this file
const extractTextFromPDF = async (filePath: string): Promise<string> => {
  const data = await fs.promises.readFile(filePath);
  const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({ data });

  const pdf = await loadingTask.promise;

  let text = '';
  for (let i = 1; i <= pdf.numPages; i++) {
    const page = await pdf.getPage(i);
    const content = await page.getTextContent();

    // had to add this since this type since I'd get a type error
    // despite filtering out the items that don't have the str property
    type StringItem = (typeof content.items)[0] & { str: string };

    const textItems = content.items.filter((item) =>
      item.hasOwnProperty('str'),
    ) as StringItem[];

    const pageText = textItems.map((item) => item.str).join('');

    text += pageText;
  }

  return text;
};
```

When I run `"NEXT_DEBUG_FUNCTION_SIZE=1 vercel build"` to analyze how would the vercel build look like I get the following output:

```bash
Serverless Function's pages: api/chat.js, api/test-route.js, api/upload.js
Large Dependencies               Uncompressed size  Compressed size
node_modules/canvas/build                  24.2 MB          8.22 MB <--- this dependency is used by the extractTextFromPDF function (not used, not exported)
node_modules/.prisma/client               15.21 MB          7.17 MB
node_modules/next/dist                    19.68 MB          4.87 MB
node_modules/react-dom/cjs                 1.64 MB        404.02 KB
node_modules/pdf-parse/lib                 2.09 MB        401.64 KB
node_modules/caniuse-lite/data           870.88 KB        314.89 KB
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/legacy           670.24 KB        128.73 KB
node_modules/hnswlib-node/build          338.04 KB        104.36 KB
```

However, if I remove or comment out the `extractTextFromPDF` the `canvas` dependency is not included in the build, MAGIC, the dependencies are not being bundled anymore:

```bash
Serverless function size info
Serverless Function's pages: api/chat.js, api/test-route.js, api/upload.js
Large Dependencies               Uncompressed size  Compressed size
// no canvas dependency here !!!
node_modules/.prisma/client               15.21 MB          7.17 MB
node_modules/next/dist                    19.68 MB          4.87 MB
node_modules/react-dom/cjs                 1.64 MB        404.02 KB
node_modules/pdf-parse/lib                 2.09 MB        401.64 KB
node_modules/caniuse-lite/data           870.88 KB        314.89 KB
node_modules/hnswlib-node/build          338.04 KB        104.36 KB
```

Doesn't nextjs has tree shaking in the api routes? I thought that only the code that is being used in the api route would be included in the build.

Full code can be found [here](https://github.com/esponges/gpt-langchain-upload-doc-chatbot/tree/main/pages/api)